# git bitbucket clone only specific folder of a branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a git repository with multiple branch where I am trying to clone a repository with **websitebranch1** it works fine but inside that branch i have sub folders

**/website**

**/api**

**/database**

when i clone all this are getting cloned in to server what i want is only
`/api` folder to be cloned

`git clone -b websitebranch1 --single-branch git@bitbucket.org:iamuser/websites.git`

Comment: Found Aswer Here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Comment: `git init
git sparse-checkout init
git sparse-checkout set "YOUR_DIR_PATH"
git remote add origin https://github.com/AUTH/REPO.git
git pull --depth 1 origin <SHA1_or_BRANCH_NAME>`